# Can't Run a single test when using Zeus Parallel Spec along with Rspec. Focus:true doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, zeus

Rspec provides the handy ability to 
place `focus: true` by a test to make it run in isolation. And running 
`$bundle exec rspec spec` works to make this functionality true

However, usage of parallel specs alone
`$rake parallel:spec`

or with Zeus : `$zeus rake parallel:spec`

does not work at all and results in the following

`ignoring {:focus => true}`

**Why? I do not want it to be ignored!**

Is there no way to run a single test or even a single file while using parallel specs? Trying to get it set up and debug errors that have to do with parallel processing, but I don't want to have to run the entire test suite to test a fix.

Specifying the file location afterwards such as 
`$zeus rake parallel:spec spec/features/testing_questionnaire_submission_spec.rb`

also fails to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question, and I have the same issue with parallel_tests in my configuration. As parallel_tests breaks the files into separate threads, it will not be of any benefit to run a single file multi-thread anyway.

You can see this when you run:

```
parallel_rspec spec/models/some_test.rb
```

It will say `1 processes for 1 specs, ~ 1 specs per process`.

Thus, if you want to run a single spec in `some_test.rb`, use `:focus` for that `it` or `specify` block, and then run,

```
rspec spec/models/some_test.rb
or
parallel_rspec spec/models/some_test.rb
```

it doesn't matter. If you want to run a single spec file, it's the same command just no `:focus`.

The issue that needs to be fixed is when `parallel_rspec` is run and there is a `:focus` somewhere in the tests, it should just run that one spec. Instead, it seems to run every spec in every thread except for the thread that includes the `:focus`, where it only runs that one test in that thread.

And you can see here, I don't think that this issue is going to get fixed: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/issues/114

Comment: Boom you provided the answer. I've always run tests with parallel:spec and not parallel_rspec, could be why the line syntax didn't work. Know anything about when to use which? The reason I wanted to be able to run a single test with parallel_rspec is that there's an error I'm getting that only occurs with parallel_tests (it's doesn't load twitter/bootstrap...). Being able to run only one tests means I don't need to wait 6 minutes between new fix attempts.